# neovim: vim.fn is nil

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I have a lua plugins script defining `local fn = vim.fn`. A couple of lines later it defines `local install_path = fn.stdpath('data')`. This script is called from my `init.vim` by `lua require('plugins')`.

Whenever I start nvim, I get the error message:
`Error while calling lua chunk: /home/MYUSERNAME/.config/nvim/lua/plugins.lua: attempt to index local 'fn' (a nil value)`,

So I figure, `vim.fn` is `nil`. I guess something with my setup is wrong, but I don't know what and I don't know how to debug this. The only idea I had was running `:checkhealth`. It gave me no errors:

```
health#nvim#check                                                                
========================================================================         
## Configuration                                                                 
  - OK: no issues found                                                          
                                                                                  
## Performance                                                                   
  - OK: Build type: Release                                                      
                                                                                   
## Remote Plugins                                                                
  - OK: Up to date                                                               

## terminal                                                                         
  - INFO: key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=\177                 
  - INFO: key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~                            
  - INFO: $VTE_VERSION='6003'                                                    
  - INFO: $COLORTERM='truecolor'
```

I also tried un- and reinstalling neovim already

```
$ sudo apt remove neovim
$ sudo apt install neovim
```

My machine is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

What could be the source of this bug, how can I debug and fix this?

Comment: I would strongly urge you to file this with the neovim team. You may also want to look at [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with my Ubuntu 20.04 running on WSL2.

After type nvim -v, found out sudo apt install neovim can only install older version, not sure why.

Follow this link to install a latest versioni, https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#ubuntu.
I installed stable version 0.7.2, but i guess latest pre-release version will do also.

Comment: "sudo apt install neovim can only install older version, not sure why." It's because the official apt repository does not host up-to-date neovim binary. The link you provided adds a third-party repository, where maintainers keep the neovim binary updated.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would strongly benefit from putting the actionable answer ("install the latest version by doing X, Y, Z") and from some formatting (which is Markdown). Consider an [edit] to improve the post.